# Can we put inherited style as the 0 precedence order in this complete cascading order table?

Tags: css, css-specificity, css-cascade

Would it be correct to put *inherited style" as the `0` (lowest) precedence order row in this [Complete Cascading Order table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade#complete_cascade_order)?

Or would it be more correct to add a fourth column to the [ID-CLASS-TYPE three column number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#three-column_comparison) where

1. ID contributes `1-0-0-0`
2. CLASS contributes `0-1-0-0`
3. TYPE contributes `0-0-1-0`
4. inherited style counts as `0-0-0-1`

Comment: Could you explain your second option in more detail. I don't understand it because the first 3 points are about selectors but the 4th isn't.

Comment: Neither of those is correct. Inheritance is completely external to the cascade,